# How to stop repeating values/ Null values from being output in a PL/SQL loop

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm having an issue where null values and repeating columns are being output in my stored procedure.
Currently, an array is being passed into my procedure as TYPE. I need to output all part numbers/pdc/src from the array. Currently if the records in TYPE (array) match what's in inventory there are no issues. If they don't exist then only nulls will be output for those respective columns in the cursor. 
I've tried inserting the current record in a variable and using a NVL operator but then the records just end up repeating. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
PROCEDURE iws_update (i_Tbulk_type   IN  update_bulk_type,
                      o_Cresultset   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
    partcount   VARCHAR2 (20) := NULL;
    sumcount    VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
    miscount    VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN i_Tbulk_type.FIRST .. i_Tbulk_type.LAST
    LOOP
        partcount := i_Tbulk_type (i).part_no; --
        sumcount := i_Tbulk_type (i).pdc;
        miscount := i_Tbulk_type (i).part_no;

        UPDATE inventory i               -- update logic
        SET    i.diff_qty = i_Tbulk_type (i).mismatch_qty,
               i.aval_qty = ( (i.aval_qty + i.diff_qty) - i_Tbulk_type (i).mismatch_qty) 
        WHERE  i.dept_cd = i_Tbulk_type (i).pdc --First PK validation
        AND    i.src = i_Tbulk_type (i).src     --second PK validation
        AND    TRIM (i.part_no) = TRIM (i_Tbulk_type (i).part_no) -- third PK validation
        AND    i.diff_qty >= 0 -- second step in validation: diff qty must be greater than zero
        AND    ( (i.diff_qty + i.aval_qty) - i_Tbulk_type (i).mismatch_qty) >=
               0 ; -- Final condition that must be met: the sum of diff and aval quantity minus the qty passed in by the array must be greater than or equal to zero. If all conditions are met update proceeds.
        COMMIT;

        OPEN o_Cresultset FOR --cursor to send back records and flags to Back End
            SELECT t.pdc, -- array dept code
                   t.src, -- array source
                   t.part_no, -- array part no  
                   CASE WHEN i.part_no IS NULL THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END AS part_no_flag, -- if part no is null then it doesn't  exist in inventory table and will print 'FAIL' as a flag. else pass.
                   ( (i.diff_qty + i.aval_qty) - t.mismatch_qty) AS avail_qty,-- sends the quantity based on second validation method. line 440. If output is negative BE will mark as fail
                   i.diff_qty AS unmatch_qty -- prints qty. if negative BE marks as fail.
            FROM   TABLE (CAST (i_Tbulk_type AS update_bulk_type)) t
                   LEFT JOIN inventory i
                        ON   i.dept_cd = t.pdc
                        AND  i.src = t.src
                        AND  TRIM (i.part_no) = TRIM (t.part_no);
    END LOOP;
END iws_update;
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want to occur when there is a record in your collection which doesn't match an actual inventory row. It's hard to recommend anything when we don't know what needs to happen.

Comment: Also, separate from the actual question, make sure to consider a bulk operation using `FORALL`. It isn't always better, but most often is. Also, you really only need to open your result set once; if you keep the loop instead of using bulk operations, it should be moved outside of the `END LOOP;`.

Comment: I can't work out what the effect will be of opening the same cursor for each item in the array, while also joining to the same array in the cursor, and then only using the cursor opened in the last iteration. Possibly that is the issue, but frankly it's making my head hurt.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Given that the reference for opening the cursor is operating against the entire collection, and not the current row in the loop, I believe it is opening an identical set for every iteration. I don't think it will cause any bad behavior, it is just unnecessary and could slow performance.